# embedding a headless browser in C

Tags: c, dom, headless-browser, embeddable

Is any of env-js, phantom JS, slimmerJS or any of the headless browsers embeddable in a C application? This is what I need to do: I have a C application that connects to a couple of servers through HTTP & HTTPS. Up until now, I got every page, figured out what it did, (mainly Javascript), extracted the parts of code that I needed (I also implemented a very simple string parser/extracter) and implemented the flow by sending the HTML code through a (secure)Socket and reading back the response. That part still works smoothly.

That was until I bumped into a set of very complex (read: obfuscated and looong) javascript pages linked one after the other, with several scripts included, and server side programming, and then I realized that I wouldn't be able to get a "maintainable" program with the procedure I've taken.

So I have spent the last several days looking for an embeddable Javascript interpreter. Bumped into spider monkey which is embeddable in C, but since I don't have any control over the scripts received, its lack of the DOM implementation makes it unsuitable. I also considered implementing the DOM interface, but honestly is a way too long distraction from my main proyect.

Then I considered the headless browsers mentioned above. Have read all the information I found about them, looked for some sort of library to interface with them, and in abscence of such librarys, have considedered hacking the code, only to realize that even trying to hack phantomJS to embedded it in my C system would be even crazier than implementing the DOM interface in spider monkey.

The system currently works in Windows and I'm using MinGW to develop it, but its final target is to be implemented in a Raspberry PI, so the more I can have plain straight C source code, the easier it will be to move the system to its final destination. With this I mean: I can use windows libraries in the meantime if they are pre-built, but can't miss the need that they must be compilable and generated in a plain compiler. I don't have yet the Raspberry PI, but I'm not expecting any fancy development tool set (I might be wrong on this)

Lastly, for the curious inside, the system is a stock screener, generates graphics with indicators which are put in a web server and generates alerts (to send notifications of price conditions) through Yahoo Messenger (this choice was mainly due to portability and availability of source code).

I will really appreciate your help in find a way to implement/embed in C *any* Javascript interpreter that has a DOM interface implemented.

Regards.

Alfredo Meraz

Comment: NodeJS should perform well enough, even on a Raspberry Pi, and [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) provides a headless browser, so there's no real reason you'd be constrained to C. You could do the whole project in Javascript. But if you plan on using C, you should consider using [Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko) or [Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). It'd probably be easiest if you set up a headless X server. Keep in mind these browser engines are written in C++, so you might have to write C wrappers around any exposed C++ classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response James... I couldn't (and can't) see how to use NodeJS as it is stated everywhere that it works on the server side... I liked a lot how Zombie is programmed, but a) couldn't find a way to embed it b) since it requires NodeJS, I took it to work on the server side (I might be wrong on this, sorry) and c) python was an unwanted extension... I'm not really constrained to C per se, rather it's a boundary I set myself... I really won't consider moving the 4000+ lines of C I've written so far to Javascript... And thanks for the advise on Chromium Embedded :-)

Comment: There is no difference between server side and your Raspberry Pi. Server side is just a role, and the Raspberry Pi can make just as good a Linux server as any other platform.

Comment: Here are instructions to get you started with Node on the Raspberry Pi: http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi

Comment: Hi and thanks again James... Although at first glance it seems way overblown for my needs (actually it IS way overblown for my needs), it looks like you hit the nail on the head with Chromium Embedded... I'm still reading all the documentation but it seems like I can implement my task by disabling/ommiting the UI, the WebViewHost... I don't want to comment yet on my findings because I still have to digest it, but I'm investing my time to read it fully... Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Alfredo, whith which solution did you end up? Would be interesting to know what you used and if you hit any bumps...